# Incorrect collum for a specifier for collum 'codigo'

Tags: mysql

Bom dia,

Eu comecei recentemente no mysql server e esta a dar um erro q por mais q procure nao arranjo soluçao:

O meu codigo é:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
codigo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(codigo))
ENGINE= InnoDB
DEFAULT
chartset=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

E por mais que tente outras alternativas nao encontro solução o erro é sempre o mesmo

```
Incorrect collum for a specifier for collum 'codigo'
```

Se alguem souber resolver este erro agradeço a ajuda :)

Comment: Você tem uma coluna `varchar` que é auto incrementavel. Não faz sentido isso. Para ser `auto_increment` precisa ser `int` ou variação dele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o problema que vejo em seu código está nesta linha:

```
codigo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Para o valor ser incrementado ele não pode ser do tipo texto. Para chaves primarias comumente se utiliza do tipo `INT`que representa valores interios, no seu caso a chave primaria é o campo `codigo` se você trocar o `VARCHAR(30)` por `INT`, como está abaixo devera da certo.

```
codigo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Mas se você for executar o código somente alterando esta linha vai dar outro erro pois o `chartset` não se escreve desta forma correta, a forma certa é `charset` como está no código abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
codigo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(codigo))
ENGINE= InnoDB
DEFAULT
charset=utf8
COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: +1. Só incrementando: `auto_increment` **devem** ser do tipo inteiro (de qualquer tamanho, desde `tinyint` até `bigint`), mais informações (aqui)[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html]

Comment: E uma dica: usar o atributo `UNSIGNED`, para ganhar um range maior em troca de não poder usar valores negativos (já que não faria sentido um ID/código negativo)

Comment: Obrigado mas nao existe maneira de eu tornar valor do codigo reajustavel? por exemplo quando nos usamos varchar(40) mesmo q nos coloquemos o codigo 5 como ele nao tem 40 caracteres ele vai se reajustar para 1 caracter e a minha pergunta era se é possivel fazer isso com os numeros inteiros no caso?